# iPad still makes faint noise even though silent mode is turned on

Tags: ipad, audio

I use an iPad pro 3rd gen 12.9 wifi 256 GB.

I turned on silent mode from the Control Centre and even turned off system volume from settings.

I also turned off the volume of music or video

But, still, faint noise leaks from my iPad's speaker when I play video or music on this condition

How can I turn off the sound perfectly, or is it a flaw of the iPad?

If it is, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Most likely a flaw in the iPad. Get it inspected by an authorised service provider.

Comment: I’m pretty sure this is a bug. I reproduced this where the volume buttons & Control Centre didn’t help mute media — only the mute button in the video player did.